# Compound Distribution --- Log Normal Distribution with Normally Distributed Mean

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Could someone please point me to a source or suggest ways in which we can obtain the Distribution, Density Functions, Expected Value, etc. of a Log Normal Distribution whose mean (mean of the log of the variable) is distributed Normally.

## Given,

$$ X = e^{W} $$
$$ W \sim N[Y,\sigma^2_{W}]$$

$$Y \sim N[\mu_{Y},\sigma^2_{Y}]$$

## To Determine,

$$f_{X}(x), F_{X}(x), E(X), E(X^{2})$$

**Related Question when Mean is also Log Normal:**

[Compound Distribution --- Log Normal Distribution with Log Normally Distributed Mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621011/compound-distribution-log-normal-distribution-with-log-normally-distributed)

**Related General Question:**

Starting with the above special case, it quickly becomes apparent there are many combinations possible. Hence was wondering if there were general techniques to derive the density, distribution function, expected value, higher moments, conditional expectations etc. of compound distributions and some source where certain combinations and results therein were given with detailed steps and complete proofs: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1614212/compound-distributions-basic-techniques-and-key-general-results-from-first-p

Comment: The question is insignficantly different compared to your last one. Use the answer I gave you previously. Whether the mean is random or the variance is random, you're going to end up with the same general form.

Comment: Never mind. I see you changed the distribution of $X$ here.

Comment: However, the general answer still remains the same.

Comment: @Clarinetist Thanks for your pointer. Indeed your suggestion on the other questions might be an approach for all of them, though simplification tricks might be different .. Let me try to develop some answers over the next few days and post if helpful. It would also be interesting to see if people come up with other general techniques ...

Comment: See comment [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1621011/).