# Compound Distribution --- Log Normal Distribution with Log Normally Distributed Mean

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Could someone please point me to a source or suggest ways in which we can obtain the Distribution, Density Functions, Expected Value, etc. of a Log Normal Distribution whose mean (actually, the mean of the log of the variable) is distributed Log Normally.

## Given,

$$X = e^{W} $$

$$W \sim N[e^{Y},\sigma^2_{W}]$$

$$Y \sim N[\mu_{Y},\sigma^2_{Y}]$$

## To Determine,

$$f_{X}(x), F_{X}(x), E(X), E(X^{2})$$

**Related Question when Mean is Normal:**

[Compound Distribution --- Log Normal Distribution with Normally Distributed Mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1620996/compound-distribution-log-normal-distribution-with-normally-distributed-mean)

**Related General Question:**

Starting with the above special case, it quickly becomes apparent there are many combinations possible. Hence was wondering if there were general techniques to derive the density, distribution function, expected value, higher moments, conditional expectations etc. of compound distributions and some source where certain combinations and results therein were given with detailed steps and complete proofs: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1614212/compound-distributions-basic-techniques-and-key-general-results-from-first-p

Comment: You are posting a large number of these parameter mix distribution problems, ... so many that working them all out by hand will keep you busy for a while. I suggest you get a computer algebra system, and once you know how to do one, you can do them all ... assuming closed-form solutions exist, and the software can find it.

Comment: @wolfies … Thanks for your attention to this. Indeed, I started trying to get a generic technique; but could find none and received suggestions to post specific questions. Could you please elaborate on the computer algebra system that can help in this regard?

Comment: Let me suggest to stop flooding the site with minor variations of the same Ur-question and to grab a textbook covering the basics of 1. distributions, 2. normal distributions, 3. expectations of random variables. In the present case, what the hypothesis says is that $e^X=Y+\sigma_XZ$ and $e^Y=\mu_Y+\sigma_YT$ where $Z$ and $T$ are standard normal and are probably independent (although this is not mentioned in the question, but should be). Everything will be deduced from this. To reach $E(X)$ for example, one would note ...

Comment: ... that the identities above imply $X=\log(\sigma_XZ+\log(\mu_Y+\sigma_YT))$ hence $$E(X)=\iint_{\mathbb R^2}\log(\sigma_Xz+\log(\mu_Y+\sigma_Yt))\frac{e^{-(z^2+t^2)/2}}{2\pi}dzdt.$$ ...Except that, if one keeps one's eyes open, one readily sees that the hypothesis that $e^Y$ should be normal is impossible, absurd, monstrous, whatever you like to call it, since nondegenerate normal random variables are never always positive. To sum up, less questions, but with an ounce of thought in them, please.

Comment: @Did .. Thanks for this pointer. It is a typo, I have fixed it. $Y$ is normal, but the mean of $X$ is log normal or distributed as $e^{Y}$. The wording of the question was correct, I presume, but this notation was not. If any other issues, please let me know.

Comment: Again: $e^X$ normal or conditionally normal (with nonzero variance) is absurd. // Which textbook did you start to read since my previous comment?

Comment: @Did please note it was the same issue defining a log normal variable... Fixed now.

Comment: New version: now, in the notations of my previous comment, $$X=\exp(\exp(\mu_Y+\sigma_YT)+\sigma_WZ),$$ which (unless $\sigma_Y=0$) is **never integrable**. No mention of a textbook the OP would have started to peruse. Where is this going to?

Comment: @Did I am truly appreciative of your time to discuss this… So are you saying, we cannot have a log-normal distribution whose mean is distributed log-normally?  I got this book "First Look at Rigorous Probability Theory" by Jeffrey Rosenthal  sometime back (admittedly, was not able to get far), but found this other reference (and similar shorter ones on the internet) more helpful and easier to understand. http://www.norstad.org/finance/#normdist. If you have other book suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: Such distributions exist, naturally, only they are not integrable.

Comment: @Did Indeed, I meant to add that I do not find it plausible that such distributions cannot exist. Which really brings up the question, How does one go about such things? I know almost zero measure theory, vector spaces etc. But are there advanced techniques developed in some part of mathematics that can provide solutions for such things? Again, my knowledge is limited, but I believe there are many different forms of integration that have been defined. Would solving such things require other such extensions … Much appreciative of any pointers and your time thus far …

Comment: Meant to add, one of the other members suggested earlier that these would lead to horrible integrations … I could not see it when I was framing these questions .. But I see it now clearly … A truly priceless learning experience … or maturity that has been gained .. I am happy to delete some of the redundant questions, if you suggest … to reduce the noise on the forum.